# Увеличение массива без потери данных

Tags: c#, массивы

Столкнулся недавно с такой проблемой, при объявлении в массиве нового количества элементов, массив опустошается. Перевернул весь (а может и не весь) MSDN, но так и не нашел ответа.

В цикле foreach я отбираю объекты. 
Например:

```
void calc()
{
    int[] numbs = { 1, 5, 2, 4, 6 };
    int[] clear;

    foreach (int num in numbs)
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
        {
            //тут я хочу что бы мой num добавился в массив clear
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам массив, простите? Почему не `List<int>`? Вы сами себе создаёте проблемы. Просто не пользуйтесь мезозойскими структурами данных.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант 1. Используем динамичский список:

```
void calc()
{
    int[] numbs = { 1, 5, 2, 4, 6 };
    var list = new List<int>();

    foreach (int num in numbs)
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
        {
            list.Add(num);
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }

    }
    int[] clear = list.ToArray();
}
```

Вариант 2. с использование LINQ:

```
void calc()
{
    int[] numbs = { 1, 5, 2, 4, 6 };
    int[] clear = numbs.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).ToArray();
}
```

Вариант 3. без сторонних библиотек, копируем элементы массива один раз:

```
void calc()
{
    int[] numbs = { 1, 5, 2, 4, 6 };
    int[] clear = new int[numbs.Length];
    var index = 0;

    foreach (var num in numbs)
    {
        if (num % 2 != 0) continue;
        clear[index++] = num;
    }

    clear = ArrayCopy(clear, index); 
}

int[] ArrayCopy(int[] array, int length)
{
    var newArray = new int[length];
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я вообще листаме редко пользовался, теперь буду)

Answer (score 3):

Ответ **pavelip** более логичен и правилен, но если по какой-то причине коллекции, LINQ и прочие радости жизни - не Ваш путь, то можно и так

```
int[] AddElement(int[] array, int element)
{
    int[] newArray = new int[array.Length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    newArray[newArray.Length - 1] = element;
    return newArray;
}

void calc()
{
    int[] numbs = { 1, 5, 2, 4, 6 };
    int[] clear = new int[0];

    foreach (int num in numbs)
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
        {
            clear = AddElement(clear, num);
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно, проще через [`Array.Resize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348051.aspx).

Comment: @VladD, проще всего через LINQ, как **pavelip** описал, но мне кажется, что вопрос был не в проще, а в понятнее... А так, я полностью с Вами согласен.

Comment: @elp87 ну создавать новый массив и копировать все элементы на каждый вызов - это не айс :(

Comment: @pavelip: Ну, с выбранной структурой данных по-другому по сути и не получится.

Comment: @VladD на каждый вызов AddElement создается и копируется новый массив. на каждый вызов, Карл! можно копировать один раз в конце. мой ответ.

Comment: @pavelip: Ну, а как работает `Enumerable.ToArray`? Данные собираются в `List<int>`, подсчитывается их количество, заводится массив нужной длины, и туда копируются элементы. То есть это по сути использование `List<int>`. Если автор хочет оставаться в рамках массива, то нужно либо два прохода (подсчёт, затем выделить массив, затем положить данные), либо реаллокация каждый раз. Choose your poison.

Comment: @VladD да, я же про метод AddElement. Вы его читали??? При чем тут ToArray()?

Comment: @pavelip: Читал, да. Ещё раз: оставаясь в рамках одного массива, это невозможно.

Comment: @VladD Вы видели мою реализацию (третий вариант)? Копирование происходит один раз. На каждой итерации я работаю с одним массивом. Тут описан очень неоптимальный код :( Только об этом я хотел сказать в своем комментарии. Спасибо.

Comment: @pavelip, я отлично отдаю себе отчет, что мой вариант неоптимален и некрасив с точки зрения правил хорошего кода. Но я пытался написать код наиболее понятный для всех

Comment: @pavelip: Окей, да. Но вы выделяете больше памяти, чем необходимо. Это может быть и невозможно. Представьте себе ситуацию, когда данных очень много, а фильтр оставляет очень мало данных.

Comment: @VladD стандартный выбор: память или скорость ;)

Comment: @pavelip: Это да. В любом случае, решение с LINQ на мой вкус лучше всего.